# how to ensure that the service is getting called?

Tags: service, telnet

I have one Batch job on one server which is intern calling the service on the other server.
The issue is-(we suspect)the batch job is unable to call the service,but we are not very sure.
How to ensure that service is not getting called from the network point of view.
we checked telnet between the two servers which is fine.
Is this the only way to troubleshoot?

note: we can not do the code level changes now.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of tools like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or 
[tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html) to capture the network traffic and see that your script is indeed sending o/g requests.